# json string for entire table row from a db2 trigger via a db2 function

Tags: json, function, triggers, db2

I have a trigger of this form:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TBP701_UPDATE
AFTER UPDATE ON TBP701 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD_ROW 
NEW AS NEW_ROW 
FOR EACH ROW 
MODE DB2SQL 
INSERT INTO TBP702 ( ID , IRN , EVENT , OLDVALUES , NEWVALUES , USER , ENTRYTIME ) 
VALUES ( DEFAULT , NEW_ROW . COLUMN1 , 'BUYBACK_ADD' , 
'{"column1":"' CONCAT OLD_ROW . COLUMN1 CONCAT '","column2":"' CONCAT OLD_ROW . COLUMN2 CONCAT '","column3":"' CONCAT OLD_ROW . COLUMN3 CONCAT '"}' ,
'{"column1":"' CONCAT NEW_ROW . COLUMN1 CONCAT '","column2":"' CONCAT NEW_ROW . COLUMN2 CONCAT '","column3":"' CONCAT NEW_ROW . COLUMN3 CONCAT '"}' ,
USER , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ;
```

I need the old and the new values in tbp701 to be inserted in a new table in json format. In the above query I have hard coded the JSON string; but I need to write such triggers on 100s of tables. So I need a sql function that can take in the following two parameters

1. NEW_ROW/OLD_ROW reference from the trigger and
2. the table name

It should return me the json string with all the columns of that particular table and row on which the trigger has been fired. I can then reuse that function for all my triggers.

I am a new-by to such advanced features in db2 concepts. So a descriptive answer would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adopting this design would be a terrible mistake.

Creating an entire second schema to hold relational data in JSON format would be a massive nightmare.  Ensuring consistency (i.e. via these triggers) would add significant overhead.

Why not just have your application layer parse the relational data and put it in JSON format?

Alternatively you might also consider storing the data in XML format (and leveraging the pureXML features in DB2).  There's a [developerWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-db2JSONpt1/) about this topic.